# cisco port forwarding to internal webserver

Tags: router, nat, cisco

I have one public ip 123.123.123.3 and this is the router port on cisco router.MY website is running on pc4 IP:192.168.0.3.
All the internal traffic is going outside by doing nat.My website is bind with the public IP: 123.123.123.3(www.example.com), Here problem is whenever i hit www.example.com from outside world i can't able to access my website.
Please let me know where i am doing wrong.I have to do something like whenever i hit www.example.com router redirect traffic to internal webserver.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that port forwarding is setup in two directions ?

1.Inside to outside : internal network trying to go out to the
    internet.
 2. Outside to inside : incoming requests coming in to the
        webserver from the internet

Make sure both are configured on your router. 
If you have both configured, then make sure your router is correctly sending/NATting to port 80.

Comment: on the router interface i have implement ip nat outside  and on the other interface configured ip nat inside. While accesslist is:  
 ip nat inside source list 105 interface GigabitEthernet0/0 overload
And 
access-list 105 permit ip any any.

I dont know where i am missing

Comment: Please follow this link and keep me posted with results, after doing the config, show me what ur trying and NAT logs : http://www.firewall.cx/cisco-technical-knowledgebase/cisco-routers/260-cisco-router-nat-overload.html

Answer (score 0):

The first you should configure Port forwarding on your cisco router, By do simple command:

Router(config)#ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.0.3 80 123.23.123.3 80

- which 80 is http port number